# Time tracking tool for monitoring application usage

Tags: windows, logging, productivity, time-management

I want to know how I'm really using my computer, and where the time goes (I have an English paper due, and I intend on getting it done, it's 2:30 PM... no wait, it's 8:30 PM...).

Which software can tell me:

1. What programs I use, and when
2. Within programs like Google Chrome or Firefox, which tabs I spend the most time on. (I would then know if I'm spending the time playing a game, or watching a movie on Hulu...)

Comment: [Wakoopa](http://social.wakoopa.com) is quite cool for this.

Comment: @Gareth Why not add that as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Procrastitracker](https://github.com/aardappel/procrastitracker) is free & suits your needs well.

> Is there a program that can give me a detailed report on how long certain processes run per day?

[image: ProcrastiTracker]

Comment: Thanks (+1). Can either of these help me figure out which tabs I focus on the most?

Comment: Procrastitracker will give you all the details. Wakoopa is a good aggregator of programs that you've run, Procrastitracker will give you the details @Wizlog

Comment: Intended to check out Wakoopa, but it turns out that it have been shut down.

Comment: @TrolleFar yeah, sadly it shut down few months ago. I'll edit it out, thanks for reminding

Comment: Virustotal detects a virus in the latest link provided

Answer (score 4):

I found this application from a [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/324076/monitor-application-usage-with-rescuetime):  [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/).  It has both paid and free services with analytics available.

I also found this one: [Kiwi](http://www.drinkprog.com/kiwi/), but it seems to be more of monitoring memory and CPU usage than applications and browser tabs in the way you need.

Comment: "I just signed up for the free version of RescueTime, so I will update this answer with further findings." Thanks very much (I don't think I've ever seen someone so dedicated to an answer before)!  I doubt it will be necessary for you to be bothered with my software updates for software updates you may not even want.  Again, thanks alot, and welcome to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Time Tracker Pro  for Mac.

It's an app that automatically tracks what apps and documents you're working on.  So no reason to enter all that manually.

(Disclosure: I'm the author)

Comment: Do you also have one for Windows?

Comment: Not yet, but we're planning to release one soon.  You can signup on our mailing list (bottom link on the website), and we'll email you when it's ready.

Comment: I think you mean "disclosure." ;)