# How to find more information on my most recently used applications?

Tags: windows-7

The Windows 7 start menu keeps a list of frequently used applications, but I can only see 30 of them (I would like to see as many as possible), and it doesn't provide any actual frequency/last used information. Is there some way that I can see this information?

Ultimately I would like to see a list of all my programs and the date that there were last used on, but in "add or remove programs" the column for "last used on" appears blank, and googling suggests that Windows 7 does not even track this information.

It obviously tracks *some* information of frequency use because the start menu's suggestions accurately reflect my most frequently used applications.

Comment: you can type `shell:recent` in command or navigate to `C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` to find out what it has as history. Anything else, you'll need a third party tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time tracking tool for monitoring application usage](http://superuser.com/questions/360067/time-tracking-tool-for-monitoring-application-usage)

Comment: The MRU (Most Recently Used) list in Windows uses the alphabet to track the entries, therefor it's limited to 26 entries maximum.  They also only track the file name and path.  File access times and dates are file-independent.

Comment: @Raystafarian `shell:recent` gives a syntax error and `C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` comes up empty.

Comment: @Raystafarian I realize now you meant type `shell:recent` as a run command, not a shell command, but nevertheless the resulting directory is empty.